# Librabbitmq 2.0.0 with Python 3 gives TypeError: can't pickle memoryview objects

Tags: celery, amqp, py-amqplib, librabbitmq

I am using the latest master branch of the git repo https://github.com/celery/librabbitmq and installing `librabbitmq==2.0.0` for Python 3.6 by following the instructions in the readme

### Using the development version

You can clone the repository by doing the following:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/celery/librabbitmq.git
```

Then install it by doing the following:

```
$ cd librabbitmq
$ make install        # or make develop
```

This works fine (after installing certain binaries for c compliation in the OS), but when I then make a small `a+b` add task and call it with `add.delay(2,2)` it fails with the following error. I looked up and saw that Celery 4 uses json as serializer, so clearly it is not because if pickle serialization

1. Changing from librabbitmq to pyamqp broker works normally
2. Same exact situation in both MacOS and Ubuntu 16

> [2018-04-30 23:40:02,956: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error:
>   SystemError(' returned a result with an error set',)   Traceback (most
>   recent call last):      File
>   "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py",
>   line 624, in _receive_callback
>         return on_m(message) if on_m else self.receive(decoded, message)      File
>   "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py",
>   line 570, in on_task_received
>         callbacks,    File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/strategy.py",
>   line 145, in task_message_handler
>         handle(req)       File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py",
>   line 221, in _process_task_sem
>         return self._quick_acquire(self._process_task, req)       File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/async/semaphore.py",
>   line 62, in acquire
>         callback(*partial_args, **partial_kwargs)     File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py",
>   line 226, in _process_task
>         req.execute_using_pool(self.pool)     File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/request.py",
>   line 531, in execute_using_pool
>         correlation_id=task_id,       File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/concurrency/base.py",
>   line 155, in apply_async
>         **options)    File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/pool.py",
>   line 1486, in apply_async
>         self._quick_put((TASK, (result._job, None, func, args, kwds)))    File
>   "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/concurrency/asynpool.py",
>   line 813, in send_job
>         body = dumps(tup, protocol=protocol)    TypeError: can't pickle memoryview objects
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):    File
>   "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py",
>   line 203, in start
>         self.blueprint.start(self)    File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py",
>   line 119, in start
>         step.start(parent)    File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py",
>   line 370, in start
>         return self.obj.start()       File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py",
>   line 320, in start
>         blueprint.start(self)     File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py",
>   line 119, in start
>         step.start(parent)    File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py",
>   line 596, in start
>         c.loop(*c.loop_args())    File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py",
>   line 88, in asynloop
>         next(loop)    File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/async/hub.py",
>   line 354, in create_loop
>         cb(*cbargs)       File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/base.py",
>   line 236, in on_readable
>         reader(loop)      File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/base.py",
>   line 218, in _read
>         drain_events(timeout=0)       File "/Users/somghosh/.virtualenvs/ctdb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librabbitmq-2.0.0-py3.6-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/librabbitmq/**init**.py",
>   line 227, in drain_events
>         self._basic_recv(timeout)   SystemError:  returned a result with an error set

Answer (score 0):

This library is not recommended to use as rabbitmq broker with celery. Instead please try py-amqp. this is more maintained and less buggy.

Comment: the documentation recommends using `librabbitmq` as they claim it is optimized

Comment: I am a core maintainer of that project :)